# Should I reference 'this' in local variable?

Tags: javascript, performance, this

I often see this in code: `var me = this;`. Why is that? Is there some performance gain if I reference 'this' in local variable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's useful if there are functions *inside* a function, such that code in those nested functions needs access to the value of `this` from the outer context.

```
function example() {
  var me = this;
  document.getElementById('whatever').onclick = function() {
    me.clicked = 1;
  };
}
```

Because `this` is established anew for every function call, without stashing the outer `this` in a variable there'd be no way to reference it at all from the inner function.

Answer (score 4):

This is used to save reference to `this`. Later in the code there's an AJAX call with a callback (for example). So, inside of that callback `this` is not the same as outside. That's why people back up "outer" `this` to a variable.

I personally like to use this form:

```
var that = this;
```

Looks funny :)

By the way, [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/), which is a kind of "javascript done right", has a fix for this as well.

It has two forms for function definition, thin arrow and fat arrow. Thin arrow behaves exactly like in javascript, and fat arrow automatically binds `this` to a value from outer context.

So, this coffeescript

```
Account = (customer, cart) -> # thin arrow
  @customer = customer
  @cart = cart

  $('.shopping_cart').bind 'click', (event) => # fat arrow
    @customer.purchase @cart
```

gets transformed to this javascript

```
var Account;
Account = function(customer, cart) {
  var _this = this;
  this.customer = customer;
  this.cart = cart;
  return $('.shopping_cart').bind('click', function(event) {
    return _this.customer.purchase(_this.cart);
  });
};
```

Cool, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

It is so that when `this` changes, you still have a reference to `this` at the point in the code you need.

Answer (score 1):

IMO it's unusual you'd see that on its own--it's a construct almost always used when there are closures involved to avoid JS's treatment of the `this` value, evaluated during execution, not declaration.

Answer (score 1):

That is often used for callback methods, where the scope would be different when the callback runs.

Example:

```
var me = this;
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
  // here "this" will be "window", so "me" is used to access the object
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The usual reason is that the code contains a closure that will get called at some later time, and the author wants to make sure the closure has access to the current `this`. Example:

Here's code that people frequently write incorrectly, like this:

```
var obj = {
    name: "Fred",
    foo: function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            alert(this.name); // <=== Fails, `this` is no longer `obj`
        }, 1000);
    }
};
obj.foo();
```

Here's that `var me = this;` applied to it:

```
var obj = {
    name: "Fred",
    foo: function() {
        var me = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
            alert(me.name); // <=== Works now
        }, 1000);
    }
};
obj.foo();
```

This comes about because in JavaScript, `this` is defined entirely by *how a function is called*, not where the function is defined.

More reading *(disclosure: both are links to my blog)*:

- [You must remember `this`](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)
- [Closures are not complicated](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)

Answer (score 0):

That is for closure scope. Look at the difference in these two jQuery plugins:

```
$.fn.blinkClosure = function() {
    var jQueryMonad = this, toggleClass = this.toggleClass;
    setInterval(function() {
        toggleClass.apply(jQueryMonad, ['invisible']);
    }, 500);
};
```

The problem is with `setInterval`. When the function in `setInterval` gets called, it starts a new chain of execution, and `this` in that chain is bound to `window`. In the closure example, we keep a reference to the jQuery object we apply the plugin to in the `jQueryMonad` (or `me` in your code). This way, we can keep our scope correct in javascript.

```
$.fn.blink = function() {
    setInterval($.proxy(function() {
        this.toggleClass('invisible');
    }, this), 500);
};
```

In the second example, `jQuery.proxy` handles that for you.

This is to solve the issues when javascript binds `this` at execution time, instead of creation time.

Answer (score 0):

It is used with inner functions. As you know, you can have functions in object constructors and there can be functions inside functions. If you see the code below.

```
function Circle(radius){
this.radius=radius;
this.getArea=function(){
                    var changeRadius=function(){
                            this.radius=20; //here this points to global
                        }
                    changeRadius();
                    return Math.PI*Math.pow(this.radius, 2);
                    }
}

var cd= new Circle(10);
console.log(cd.getArea());
```

When you call getArea(), you will get area according to radius 10. Although you are calling changeRadius() but inside inner function changeRadius, this starts to point to global object instead of the object you created. You use var `self=this construct` to get around here.

so in order to get around this situation we can have the following changes.

```
function Circle(radius){
var self=this;
this.radius=radius;
this.getArea=function(){
                    var changeRadius=function(){
                            self.radius=20;
                        }
                    changeRadius();
                    return Math.PI*Math.pow(this.radius, 2);
                    }
}

var cd= new Circle(10);
console.log(cd.getArea());
```