# setInterval invoked from inside an object Javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, canvas, game-engine

I am trying to make a game engine with Jvascript. So far I have:

```
function gameEngine() {

    this.canvas = $('canvas')[0];
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.framerate = 20;

    this.resetCanvas = function() {
        this.ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
        this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    };

    this.loop = function() {
        this.resetCanvas();
    };

    this.run = function() {
        setInterval(this.loop, this.framerate);
    };
}

new gameEngine();
```

But the canvas is not showing up; why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`this` is becoming detached when passing `this.loop` to `setInterval`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11853792/139010) Common solutions:

[`Function.bind`:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
this.run = function() {
    setInterval(this.loop.bind(this), this.framerate);
};
```

Or [use a closure:](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9602700/139010)

```
var self = this;
this.run = function() {
    setInterval(function () {
        self.loop();
    }, this.framerate);
};
```

Then you need to actually *call* the `run` method:

```
new gameEngine().run();

// or 

function gameEngine() {

    // snip...

    this.run();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, this has helped alot :) will accept when I can!

Comment: Would you use the bind method or the closure method? Does it matter and thanks again!

Comment: I prefer `Function.bind` but if you plan on supporting older versions of IE (ugh, I can't believe I'm still talking about this in 2013...) then you'll need to [provide a `Function.bind` shim.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility)

Answer (score 1):

You never call `setInterval`.

```
var ngin = new gameEngine();
ngin.run();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `run()` function on your `gameEngine` after you initialize it. You may also want to store your `gameEngine` in a variable.

Example:

```
var myGameEngine = new gameEngine();
myGameEngine.run();
```

Or if you don't want to have to call run, stick `this.run()` at the end of your object definition. That eliminates the need to store a reference to your `gameEngine` object, although you probably still should for later reference.

Comment: I do not recommend having the constructor do any work other than initialize values (re: paragraph 2).  JSLint will even complain about this